# Unpredictable behavior when accessing View from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I was trying to build an app which have some thread usage. While working I found unpredictable behavior while I was trying to access a TextView from thread. **I know android forbid us from accessing views directly from another thread.I also know how to access main thread's views from another thread using AsyncTask, Handler , Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) , View.post(Runnable) , View.postDelayed(Runnable, long) etc.**

Here is my code snippet -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                /*try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                /*for(int i= 0 ; i<10000000 ;i++){
                    Log.i("logger"," i ="+i);
                    tv.setText("i = "+i);
                }*/

                tv.setText("This is the new text");
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

When I am running this code , no crash occur but as soon as I uncomment Thread.sleep() or for loop part ,crash occur.
**Can anyone explain this behavior , why it happening like this and why crash is not occurring with given code.Please don't post answers explaining how to do it.**

Thanks in advance.

This is the crash log when I uncomment Thread.sleep() code section -

```
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13346
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5225)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1062)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15316)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6659)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3670)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3528)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3503)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at com.example.sampleproject.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:33)
05-26 21:11:47.244: E/AndroidRuntime(14310):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
05-26 21:11:47.284: D/memalloc(14310): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5432a000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:66
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of a race condition.

Essentially the crash comes when the view tries to invalidate itself in a wrong thread. `setText()` does not invalidate the view unless the view has been measured at least once and the `TextView` has a non-null `mLayout`.

When you create a new view hierarchy with `setContentView()`, the message that measures the views is posted on the UI thread's queue but the chances are your thread gets to run before the measure pass has created a layout for the text view.

For details, examine the [source](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#3922).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update UI from another thread, use this instead

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText("This is the new text");
                    }
                });  
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

If you want to know more here a good article:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Comment: Androidster has already mentioned : "I also know how to access main thread's views from another thread using AsyncTask, Handler , Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable) , View.post(Runnable) , View.postDelayed(Runnable, long) etc.". But he wants to know why the code is working without sleep and not with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing any code that interacts with the UI like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      // Put your UI interactions here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

below code working fine for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                Bundle data = msg.getData();
                String result=data.getString("key");
                textview.setText(result);
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("key","you data");
                    Message message=new Message();
                    message.setData(bundle);
                    handler.sendMessage(message);

                }
            });
            t.start();

        }
    }
```